# While integration testing, ActionController::ParameterMissing appears, despite logs to the contrary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, integration-testing

I have installed Rails using the instructions from https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/16.04 on an Ubuntu 16.04 amd64 server.  I used 'rbenv' rather than any of the other options.

I created a new application named 'testapp'.

I then executed:

```
$ rails generate scaffold Test name:string age:integer
```

Then, I executed:

```
$ bin/rails generate integration_test tests_post
```

I modified test/integration/tests_post_test.rb to read as follows:

```ruby
require 'test_helper'

class TestsPostTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "can create an item" do
    get "/tests/new"
    assert_response :success
    post "/tests",
      params: { test: { name: 'Micky Mouse', age: 120 } }
    assert_response :redirect
    follow_redirect!
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

And then I executed:

```
rake test
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Run options: --seed 24994

# Running:

.......E

Finished in 0.247049s, 32.3822 runs/s, 56.6689 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
TestsPostTest#test_can_create_an_item:
ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: test
    app/controllers/tests_controller.rb:72:in `test_params'
    app/controllers/tests_controller.rb:27:in `create'
    test/integration/tests_post_test.rb:8:in `block in <class:TestsPostTest>'

8 runs, 14 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Yet, the relevant logging shows the following:

```
--------------------------------------
TestsPostTest: test_can_create_an_item
--------------------------------------
Started GET "/tests/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-09-30 07:50:18 -0400
Processing by TestsController#new as HTML
  Rendered tests/_form.html.erb (13.6ms)
  Rendered tests/new.html.erb within layouts/application (16.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 170ms (Views: 161.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started POST "/tests" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-09-30 07:50:19 -0400
Processing by TestsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"params"=>{"test"=>{"name"=>"Mickey Mouse", "age"=>"120"}}}
Completed 400 Bad Request in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

In development and in production, this gives no errors, only in test.  I keep looking over examples I've seen online in other projects, but I don't see that I'm doing anything particularly out of the ordinary here.  I created these specific steps to show the problem as simply as possible.  Any ideas how to get this to work properly?  Is there perhaps a bug in this version of rake (11.3.0)?

Comment: What's in your `TestController`, particularly on line 72?

Comment: params.require(:test).permit(:name, :age), but that isn't the nature of this problem.  Alexandre Angelim had it... just had to change the way I specified the params in the test.

Comment: You should learn how to debug these problems, rather than memorising certain solutions like this... You could have simply placed a `binding.pry` above that line, and inspected the current value of `params` -- that would have made the solution fairly obvious.

Comment: I shall endeavor to use such methods as I learn more about rails programming, and the various tools available to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably using Rails 4(given the installation tutorial you're following). For Rails 4 you don't need to wrap your params when posting on integration tests. Change the line:

```
post "/tests", params: { test: { name: 'Micky Mouse', age: 120 } }
```

to

```
post "/tests", { test: { name: 'Micky Mouse', age: 120 } }
```

and you'll be fine.

Comment: "You don't need to wrap" - you do, since rails 5

Comment: Yep, that's the answer.  I'm using 4.2, and apparently all the samples I've been examining were for 5.0.  Thank you!